# Robot Framework - Browser Library - can't click or read value inside a details/summary tag

Tags: robotframework, html-tag-details

I have the following details/summary tags and I am trying to run automated test to simulate click on the details drop down or just get the value of the `<p>` tag within

```
<tvar data-tvar="en_content">
 <details class="wb-details" close="close">
  <summary>Clickable summary</summary>
  <p>test123</p>
 </details>
</tvar>
```

I've tried the following using Browser Library but none see the 'test123' inside of the `<p>` tag.
'Click' does not work.  It never opens and shows the value in the screenshots.
'Get Text' times out because it cannot find the value or says it doesn't match.

```
Get Text    xpath=//tvar[@data-tvar="en_content"]/details/p    contains    test123
Get Text    xpath=//tvar[@data-tvar="en_content"]/details      contains    test123
Get Text    xpath=//tvar[@data-tvar="en_content"]              contains    test123

Click    xpath=//tvar[@data-tvar="en_content"]/details/p  
Click    xpath=//tvar[@data-tvar="en_content"]/details
Click    xpath=//tvar[@data-tvar="en_content"]
Click    xpath=//tvar[@data-tvar="en_content"]/details/summary
```

Comment: ["First questions" review:] You are referring to "screenshots". Would providing these screenshots help the community to understand/answer the question?